# What is instead max_matches?

Tags: sphinx

I have a Sphinx 2.2.7.
In this version, "max_matches" is deprecated. What could I use instead?

A result of my query has in average 20000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just the server wide 'cap' that is being deprecated.

It still exists as a query time parameter. It defaults to 1000, but can be overridden on a per query basis.

Comment: Thanks, I have added: option max_matches = 20000 , to a query.